# Multiple css rules with ternary operator

Tags: jquery, css, ternary-operator

Within a `.hover()` event, I have the following code:

```
$(this).css('background-position', circle.includesXY(e.pageX, e.pageY) ? 'bottom' : '');
```

Could somebody explain how I can add more property:value pairs to `.css()` without compromising the ternary operator? If not, how should it be rewritten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.css` also accepts an object:

```
$(this).css(circle.includesXY(e.pageX, e.pageY)
   ? {
      property1: 'value1',
      property2: 'value2'
   }
   : {
      property1: 'value3',
      property2: 'value4'
   }
);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Now I know the syntax, I should find out exactly what this means :)